# Cannot execute python file from lua script

Tags: python, lua, path, python-3.7

```
os.execute("C:\\py+lua\\parser.py")
```

I call this command from lua script. It is not working for me. os.execute returns 0.
Python 3.7 is installed

Edited.
It started working this way:

```
os.execute("C:\\InstallPython\\python.exe C:\\py+lua\\parser.py")
```

Comment: What is parser.py supposed to accomplish? Is it supposed to return 0?

Comment: No. Parser go to site and grab information from it. It writes values in file.

Comment: Does it actually write out the file? Can you reduce the code in parser.py to a [mcve] and post it? Right now, it isn't clear if Python is failing to get called at all or whether your Python code is triggering an error of some sort (e.g. syntax error, file write permissions error, etc.). You need to figure that out if you want to have any hope of resolving the problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a feature that allows you to answer your own question. Since you found the answer to your question yourself, I would recommend using this feature and marking your answer as accepted so that people can easily find the solution to this problem. It will also show people who are looking for people to help that this problem has already been solved and that they shouldn't spend time looking at this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your parser file needs to grab information from a site, i would recommed to use python within lua.

```
py = require 'python'
parser = py.import parser
getFile = parser() -- this will call you python funtion
```

Comment: You mean Lunatic Python? I have problems installing it. I described them here: https://github.com/bastibe/lunatic-python/issues/67